# Multiple Image Selecting from gallery on xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, image-gallery

I have a project that I need to select multiple images from gallery on xamarin forms, there is some options like [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) but this plugin is not allow to select multiple images. there was another option with ELCImagePicker , but now ELCImagePicker is no longer supported on updated xamarin forms (Can not find at NuGet packages). Now there is no any other option to get multiple images from gallery with xamarin forms. Do you know how to do it ? I'm stuck with this.

Comment: you can use Objective Sharpie to bind an iOS SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there I found a library called  GMImagePicker ported from written in objective-c. compatible with Xamarin.iOS ,It allows multiple Image selection , be aware that you should do some modifications to work with iCloud. It works with PHAsset. Asset Image stream , file Url and other details can be managed by `PHAssetImageManager`

[GMImagePicker For Xamarin](https://github.com/roycornelissen/GMImagePicker.Xamarin)

Comment: Can you please share the sample codes in IOS Mediaservice? I go through the GMImagePicker usage part but didn't find how to add the selected images to 'List' and pass that value in `MessagingCenter`. In that usage part only telling about the `picker` settings. Can you please give me any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

This question is relatively old, but through the months of building Xamarin software for our clients, I have seen this question pop up dozens of times in the course of searching for various pieces for my code. I figured that since I've found an important answer, I should share it for the sake of anyone else who will come across this question.

[James Montemagno](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno) has [added support for selecting multiple photos](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/pull/650) using the OP's mentioned [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)! The previous implementation of calling

```
MediaFile result = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
```

returns a single result of type `MediaFile`. The new implementation

```
List<MediaFile> result = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotosAsync();
```

returns a list result of type `List<MediaFile>`. Make sure to check the documentation on Montemagno's page for the details on how to correctly set up and run the code.

***Very important note:***
After testing multiple different options, including Montemagno's MediaPlugin, it is clear that picking multiple photos is not supported on certain Android devices, as a function of the manufacturer's software. Multiple folks have opened [issues](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/697) on Montemagno's page, but it's not something his team can fix. I don't have an answer for that upcoming question, but hopefully something will develop soon.