# Xamarin Forms Select Multiple images, Cancel and Rearrange

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, file-upload

I have been trying to use Xam.Plugin.Media to select multiple images. However the latest stable version 5.0.1 is buggy and the image comes like a Black Square. The older version works but doesn't have multiple selection options and sometimes unexpectedly inverts the chosen image.

I am looking for a way to choose multiple images from iOS & Android gallery. Auto-arrange to see them on my phone screen, cancel one or more images and able to Re-arrange/ReOrder them before uploading to my API.

Is there any document or form or code I can refer as an intermediate developer to fix this?

Comment: Check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022214/multiple-image-selecting-from-gallery-on-xamarin-forms

Comment: This seems helpful. However, its just for Xamarin.iOS. Is there a way to use this with Android ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix part of my problem. The Xam.Plugin.Media 5.0.1 has some issues while saving MetaData. Hence if you set SaveMetaData = false in PickMediaOptions, the black square goes away and i can see the selected image.

Also, I was able to add a cancel icon on each image by using a grid. These grids are dynamically created depending upon the images selected. I add an  and a  (icon) in the grid. The button is binded to the Image's media file. This entire structure is then put inside a flexlayout. Whenever a user click the cancel button on the image, i just find the binded media file and remove it from the flexlayout children. (The grid is also binded by the same Media file.)

Now all I need is to come up with a way where I can drag and drop to rearrange these grid elements in my flexlayout.

Comment: Maybe you could look at [PanGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pan) and refer [here](https://github.com/framinosona/Xamarin-Developer-Sample)